# Can not sign transaction with signer get from mnemonic

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, chai, mnemonic

**I'm writing test for MAX_SUPPLY of this function**

// contract.sol

```
function mintStandard() public payable whenNotPaused {
        require(
            _standardCounter.current() <= 2222,
            "Sorry we reach max supply"
        );
        require(
            balanceOf(msg.sender, STANDARD) == 0,
            "You can only own 1 Standard NFT"
        );
        require(msg.value == 0.25 ether, "insufficient balance");
        _mint(msg.sender, STANDARD, 1, "0x00");
        _standardCounter.increment();
    }
```

// test.js

```js
const { expect, assert } = require('chai');
const { loadFixture } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
require('dotenv').config()

describe('NFT contract function test', function() {
    async function deployContract() {
        const [ owner, signer ] = await ethers.getSigners();
    
        const NFT = await ethers.getContractFactory('NFT');
        const nft = await NFT.deploy();

        const price = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25");

        return {nft, owner, signer, price };
    }

    it('Should let mint only 2222 NFT', async function () {
            const {owner, nft, price} = await loadFixture(deployContract);

            const hdNode = await ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(process.env.SEED_PHRASE)
        
            for (let i = 0; i < 2222; i++) {
                const signers = await ethers.getSigner(hdNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/${i}`).address);

                console.log('creating signer: ', signers.address)

                const tx = {
                    to: signers.address,
                    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
                }
                console.log('creating transaction: ', tx)

                const txn = await owner.sendTransaction(tx);
                console.log('Mining transaction...')

                await txn.wait()
                console.log('Transaction mined!')

                await nft.connect(signers).mintStandard({value:price})
                console.log('Minting nft')

                expect(await nft.balanceOf(signer.address, 0)).to.be.equal(1);
            }

        })
    })
```

**keep getting this error**

```
InvalidInputError: unknown account 0x4f099cfbc4043e60c52ef47ebc593ba0bda5c85e
      at HardhatNode.getSignedTransaction (/home/dtnwen/learn/diploma/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:481:11)
      at EthModule._sendTransactionAction (/home/dtnwen/learn/diploma/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1046:33)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/home/dtnwen/learn/diploma/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:123:18)
      at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/home/dtnwen/learn/diploma/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

when I tried to debug, I find out that my `signers` instance get from `` const signers = await ethers.getSigner(hdNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/${i}`).address); `` doesn't have fields:

```
_network: { chainId: 31337, name: 'unknown' },
    _internalBlockNumber: Promise { [Object] },
    _fastBlockNumber: 0,
    _fastBlockNumberPromise: Promise { 0 }
```

**Is that the problem? If not then why?**

// console

```
creating signer:  0x4f099cFbC4043e60c52EF47EBC593ba0Bda5C85e
creating transaction:  {
  to: '0x4f099cFbC4043e60c52EF47EBC593ba0Bda5C85e',
  value: BigNumber { value: "1000000000000000000" }
}
Mining transaction...
Transaction mined!
      1) Should let mint only 2222 NFT
```

error at `await nft.connect(signers).mintStandard({value:price})`

// `signers` instance

```
SignerWithAddress {
  _isSigner: true,
  address: '0x4f099cFbC4043e60c52EF47EBC593ba0Bda5C85e',
  _signer: JsonRpcSigner {
    _isSigner: true,
    provider: EthersProviderWrapper {
      _isProvider: true,
      _events: [],
      _emitted: [Object],
      disableCcipRead: false,
      formatter: [Formatter],
      anyNetwork: false,
      _networkPromise: [Promise],
      _maxInternalBlockNumber: -1024,
      _lastBlockNumber: -2,
      _maxFilterBlockRange: 10,
      _pollingInterval: 4000,
      _fastQueryDate: 0,
      connection: [Object],
      _nextId: 42,
      _hardhatProvider: [BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter],
      _eventLoopCache: [Object]
    },
    _address: '0x4f099cFbC4043e60c52EF47EBC593ba0Bda5C85e',
    _index: null
  },
  provider: EthersProviderWrapper {
    _isProvider: true,
    _events: [],
    _emitted: { block: -2 },
    disableCcipRead: false,
    formatter: Formatter { formats: [Object] },
    anyNetwork: false,
    _networkPromise: Promise { <pending> },
    _maxInternalBlockNumber: -1024,
    _lastBlockNumber: -2,
    _maxFilterBlockRange: 10,
    _pollingInterval: 4000,
    _fastQueryDate: 0,
    connection: { url: 'http://localhost:8545' },
    _nextId: 42,
    _hardhatProvider: BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter {
      _wrapped: [FixedGasProvider],
      _provider: [FixedGasProvider],
      sendAsync: [Function: bound sendAsync],
      send: [Function: bound send],
      _sendJsonRpcRequest: [Function: bound _sendJsonRpcRequest] AsyncFunction
    },
    _eventLoopCache: { detectNetwork: [Promise] }
  }
}
```

// `owner` instance

```
SignerWithAddress {
  _isSigner: true,
  address: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  _signer: JsonRpcSigner {
    _isSigner: true,
    provider: EthersProviderWrapper {
      _isProvider: true,
      _events: [],
      _emitted: [Object],
      disableCcipRead: false,
      formatter: [Formatter],
      anyNetwork: false,
      _networkPromise: [Promise],
      _maxInternalBlockNumber: 0,
      _lastBlockNumber: -2,
      _maxFilterBlockRange: 10,
      _pollingInterval: 4000,
      _fastQueryDate: 1684145659967,
      connection: [Object],
      _nextId: 42,
      _hardhatProvider: [BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter],
      _eventLoopCache: [Object],
      _network: [Object],
      _internalBlockNumber: [Promise],
      _fastBlockNumber: 0,
      _fastBlockNumberPromise: [Promise]
    },
    _address: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    _index: null
  },
  provider: EthersProviderWrapper {
    _isProvider: true,
    _events: [],
    _emitted: {
      block: -2,
      't:0x4d9029bee75a2f2954c2fc9e28c9f5354a7b5132bcf1463bf2a1b2e5a5010b67': 1,
      't:0xcec1b3b6782ff589a95ec5a60f5959c099787ba2416b1b102e0f7cfefcef3444': 2
    },
    disableCcipRead: false,
    formatter: Formatter { formats: [Object] },
    anyNetwork: false,
    _networkPromise: Promise { [Object] },
    _maxInternalBlockNumber: 0,
    _lastBlockNumber: -2,
    _maxFilterBlockRange: 10,
    _pollingInterval: 4000,
    _fastQueryDate: 1684145659967,
    connection: { url: 'http://localhost:8545' },
    _nextId: 42,
    _hardhatProvider: BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter {
      _wrapped: [FixedGasProvider],
      _provider: [FixedGasProvider],
      sendAsync: [Function: bound sendAsync],
      send: [Function: bound send],
      _sendJsonRpcRequest: [Function: bound _sendJsonRpcRequest] AsyncFunction
    },
    _eventLoopCache: { detectNetwork: [Promise] },
    _network: { chainId: 31337, name: 'unknown' },
    _internalBlockNumber: Promise { [Object] },
    _fastBlockNumber: 0,
    _fastBlockNumberPromise: Promise { 0 }
  }
}
```